# Database select function in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I am trying to create a function in PHP that accepts two arguments, one being the SQL for a mysqli query and the other being the name I would like to be set as the variable name for the resulting array. Here it is so far:

```
<?php

function dbSelect($sql,$name) {
    include "connect.php";
    if($results = $db->query($sql)) {
        if($results->num_rows) {
            while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
                ${$name}[] = $row;
            }
            $results->free();
        }
    }
    return ${$name};
}
```

Within the referenced connect.php file is this code

```
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'admin', 'PASSWORD', 'DB_NAME');
```

However it does not seem to work in its current state. I do not get any errors when calling the function "dbSelect($sql, 'test');" however when I try to reference the supposedly created variable (in this case, $test) I get an undefined error.

Any suggestions or tips on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you're using, what seems to be a variables variable method. Have you tried `$name[] = $row; ... return $name;`?

Comment: If I do that I get an error Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: If there are no results returned from query, your array is not inizialized so you try to return a null array, you should initzialize $name with $name = array();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${$name}` variable you're assigning to has local scope. That is, the variable disappears as this function returns. Using a variable-variable doesn't make that variable global.

I would recommend you just name the array anything inside your function, and then `return` the array. Then you can assign its return value to your desired variable instead of passing the variable name.

```
$test = dbSelect($sql);
```

You could try to declare `global ${$name}` inside the function to write to a variable of global scope, but IMHO it's not worth it. It's a better habit to avoid writing functions that have weird side effects on global variables. Keep it simple, just `return` the results.

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain why you think this is wrong? Perhaps I can improve it.

Comment: The OP's design is dubious at best, but misunderstanding scope is likely the issue causing his problems here, so +1 from me :)

Comment: *"Downvoter, can you explain why you think this is wrong? Perhaps I can improve it."* - I couldn't agree with you more Bill. Downvoters hardly ever post a comment, only the ones with balls and the ones who don't hide behind an LCD curtain.

Comment: Im just trying to create some functionality while still using PHP, any tips on the methods I use are welcome as well :)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I see from the edit above that this question has the attention of YourCommonSense, which explains the unwarranted downvote.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yeah, it's not hard to miss that one, nor to put 2 and 2 together ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The variable variable `${$name}` has no practical use in this function.  The function returns an array with no variable name.  You name it when you assign the function return:

```
$whatEverYouWant = dbSelect('some sql');

function dbSelect($sql) {
    include "connect.php";
    if($results = $db->query($sql)) {
        if($results->num_rows) {
            while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
            $results->free();
            return $array;
        }
    }
    return false;    
}
```

Return `false` or maybe an empty `array()` if there are no results or an error.

Comment: Which resembles [`my comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126129/database-select-function-in-php#comment37223319_24126129) about `$name[] = $row; ... return $name;` yet the OP stated *"error Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings"* - It's just the names are different.